# JSF page rendering error:Faces Context

Tags: java, jsf

I am getting the below messages when my JSF page gets rendered. The page is rendered correctly however in the Console the message below repeats itself numerous times...

```
INFO: ERROR: Unable to get Faces Context for session variable: localeBean
```

11:54:27,090 INFO  [STDOUT] Nov 24, 2009 11:54:27 AM com.web.util.faces.UtilFacesFuncs log
INFO: Most likely, you've requested a Faces object from a NON-Faces (i.e. Servlet) context.

In my JSF I am usign localebean as follows:

```
<f:view locale="#{localeBean.userLocaleLoggedIn}">
```

In the faces-config file I have it defined as below:

```
<managed-bean>
    <description>Locale Bean</description>
    <managed-bean-name>localeBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.mg.faces.LocaleBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

In my class LocaleBean there is a method getUserLocaleLoggedIn() which is the code that gets executed when the JSF page executes:

```
  <f:view locale="#{localeBean.userLocaleLoggedIn}">
```

On debugging my jsp I can see that method being called and everyhting is fine, I debug my jsp all the way thru till it creates the footer, just when it is rendering to the browser these errors are thrown about 20 +  times repeatedly. It only happens on tihs jsp as it is a new one I have added. I tried comparing with existing jso I cannot see anything different, Does anyone know what I shud be looking out for?

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks.

Regards

Comment: This issue was resolved there was some page specific functions to be called before referring to this bean which made the error go away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry my comment I added above did not come across correctly, here is what I have in my web.xml:
Also my url I use is `http://localhost.com/context/register/mypage.htm`
I have these jsp under the folder register. I can call other jsp from the register folder
and this error does not appear.... just happens for this particular jsp that I have added.

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I am trying to add my full mappings but the way the code tags work here, it is not coming across since hte mappings have tags... I tried blockquotes provided, but still this editor is not able to display my mappings correctly, apologies!

Any idea how I should be calling my url. Thanks.

Comment: The order of answers is based on votes, so please edit the question in future.

Answer (score 0):

This error basically means that the request URL (the one which you see in the browser address bar, or the one which is used to include/dispatch the desired page) does **not** match the `url-pattern` of the `FacesServlet`'s mapping as definied in the `web.xml`. You need to let the request URL match it to invoke the `FacesServlet`.

So if it is for example the following suffix-pattern (extension mapping):

```
<url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
```

then you need to ensure that your request URL matches it, i.e. use http://example.com/context/page.jsf instead of http://example.com/context/page.jsp.

Or if it is for example the following prefix-pattern (directory mapping):

```
<url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
```

then you need to ensure that your request URL look like http://example.com/context/faces/page.jsp instead of http://example.com/context/page.jsp.

**Edit**: although I wouldn't use multiple `url-pattern`s for the `FacesServlet` and just stick to one, but the mapping seems to look fine. After all, the error message thus comes from `com.web.util.faces.UtilFacesFuncs`. That look like a homegrown utility class. What exactly is that class doing? Isn't it just a bug in that utility class that it for example is trying to access the `FacesContext` too early or too late in the request?

Comment: In my web.xml I have the following mappings:

 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>