# index page rendered as xml instead of html

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, glassfish

i have a web app which i have tested locally and works fine, on deployment to production server (manually without netbeansIDE) on Glassfish 3.1.2 , it deploys successfully but on running my url i see the xhtml content instead of the applications login page. What could i be missing. If i have tried re-deploying the war file with no luck.

```
ui:composition xmlns:ui='http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets' template='/WEB-INF/templates/temp.xhtml'
ui:define name='dynamicContent'
ui:composition
```

instead of the actual html markup

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does my JSF + Spring web application output JSF source code instead of interpreted HTML page?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2853964)

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/a/13515501 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/3160549 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/14156585 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/3005303 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/8041828 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/1791910 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/8097087 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/2207938 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/3331938 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/12599754 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/6477084 etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem was My netbeans IDE was using GlassFish4, and production was 3.1.2, after installation and configuration of v4 on Production everything was ok.