# JSP/JSF documents not rendering correctly after upgrade to Tomcat 7

Tags: jsp, jsf, tomcat, tomcat7

I have a JSF1.0 app that I am trying to run on Tomcat 7. It currently runs correctly on Tomcat 6.

The problem is that loading pages on Tomcat 7 presents the XML (of the JSP document containing the JSF tags) instead of parsing all the taggy goodness and emitting the desired HTML.

I have worked through the many similar issues reported here and elsewhere, including those linked to by BalusC in the comments on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17701203/index-page-rendered-as-xml-instead-of-html). None of those have helped solve the problem. The Faces servlet is correctly configured, and the app is running without problems on Tomcat 6.

I'm aware that Tomcat 7 ships new versions of the Servlet, JSP and EL specs, but I can't find (a) any evidence that this is part of the problem or (b) any guidance for new configuration required on Tomcat 7 to get my app working. The app also uses the old Struts Tiles 1, but again I have no evidence that that is the problem.

Here's some code.

Here's the JSP document. 
This (excluding the XML and jsp:root tags) is what is rendered to the browser.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jsp:root 
xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" 
xmlns:x="uri://uri/of/x"
version="1.2">  

<jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"/>  
  <x:view> 
    <html> 
... etc (lots more tags from the app's taglib x)
    </html>  
  </x:view> 
</jsp:root>
```

Here's the Faces servlet mapping

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

How do I get this lot up and running on Tomcat 7?

Comment: Which JARs do you have in webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib`? Perhaps you mistakely placed copies of Tomcat6 specific JARs such as `jsp-api.jar` in there? (which would only conflict with Tomcat7 ones). Some starters incorrectly do that in order to circumvent compilation problems in their IDE.

Comment: Hi BalusC. No, the jsp-api and servlet-api jars are not in WEB-INF/lib. The app has no jars in WEB-INF/lib that are in Tomcat's own lib folder. Other jars in the apps WEB-INF/lib include: JSF api and impl, jstl (v1.1), struts.jar (v1.2.2), tomahawk.jar (v1.1.1), and the other usual stuff; xml parsers, database drivers, apache commons. The TLD files for the apps own widget libraries are in WEB-INF/lib too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, figured this out.

The problem was Tomcat 7 not locating our custom tag libraries. Since everything (on the landing page) is a custom tag, it was just rendering the source with no parsing.

Putting the following in web.xml fixes it. I think it's JSP 2.0 syntax.
For some reason our JSP 1.2 reliance on it just finding the .tld's in WEB-INF/lib no longer works.

```
<taglib>
    <taglib-uri>uri://uri/of/x</taglib-uri>
    <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/lib/custom_tag_lib.tld</taglib-location>
</taglib>
... repeat for every custom taglib
```

After that everything seems to work. I'll roll it out on the DB&T next week and we'll see.

If I had five bucks for every line of Tomcat, Catalina, Jasper and JSF code I had to debug through to find this I'd be able to throw a darn good party.

Maybe one day this helps someone else. If anyone cares to look, the guilty code is in org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache

Comment: After some thought I filed a defect against Tomcat for the incompatible behaviour of TldLocationsCache. See here: https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55508

Answer (score 3):

TLD files should not be placed in WEB-INF/lib

See section JSP.7.3.1 of the JSP specification (2.1 for Tomcat 6, 2.2 for Tomcat 7 or 2.3 for Tomcat 8). I didn't go back and check earlier specifications.

Tomcat 6 allows you to get away with this. Tomcat 7 onwards doesn't as a result of the refactoring of TLD processing that took place between Tomcat 6 and Tomcat 7. There were various improvements in TLD handling in this refactoring. One of the other changes was following the requirements of JSP.7.3.1.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications Mark, and for the speedy response to my bug. I'm fine with the resolution, specs are specs. It would have been great to have this clearly documented somewhere as a migration step from Tomcat 6 to 7.